# A sample application in GWT + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, gwt

I've been thinking of using Spring + Hibernate with GWT, read a quite a few links on this topic but I'm not able to get started. So I'm looking for a sample application using GWT + Spring + Hibernate (at least Spring + GWT), could you please suggest any useful links.

Answer (score 2):

I found that http://code.google.com/p/tocollege-net/ is great project to start with the GWT - Spring - Hibernate. Jeff Dwyer has done good job explaining on how to do it in his book Pro Web 2.0 Application Development with GWT.